# Synchronize events of 2 different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a setup where the  onblur event of textbox is being evaluated for validation. Validation opens a confirm dialog if not valid. onclick of submit(img element) submits the form. Problem is when a user types anything in textbox and directly clicks on img button both events fire. The dialog box open but the form gets submitted as well. It shouldn't be like this: calling the blur event  should cancel the submit event or synchronize both. In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eezo/Xdjq9/2/) it works fine. Any idea what it could be? Can I check if confirm dialog is open? It's a pure javascript component. I can't figure it out if it's possible to detect. Please help!!

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eezo/Xdjq9/2/):

```
<input type='text' id='textbx'/>
<img id='btn' src='http://www.urgenthomework.com/images/submit.jpg'/>
```

Logic:

```
$('#textbx').blur(function(){
    alert("I'm blur");
});
$('#btn').click(function(){
   alert("I'm clicked!!!");
});
```

But it's working fine in fiddle. Actually I'm using autocomple plugin on textbox so on change/blur event it does validation internally, which I modified as per my need.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some codes you have tried.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: You're saying that it works on fiddle but it doesn't on your project? Are you using the same javascript library (1.7.2)?

Comment: Yes it's same, i wonder if it's because of autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add indicator.

```
$(function(){
     var isValid = false;
     $('#textbx').blur(function(){

         //some condition
         //for example if length > 4

         if($(this).val().length > 4)
         {
             isValid = true;
         }
     });
     $('#btn').click(function(){
         if(isValid)
         {
             alert("I'm clicked!!!");
         }
     });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xdjq9/3/)